# Show title bar for google chrome in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: gnome, 20.04, google-chrome, ubuntu-gnome

I noticed in Ubuntu 20.04.1 there is no longer a title bar in google chrome (the bar at the top of the window you can use to click and drag the window). Is there a way to bring this title bar back?

Answer (score 2):

Find a blank spot in the tab location. Right click on it and select "Use system title and borders."

It looks like this:

[image: use system borders]

And the results are:

[image: result]

Note that mine is dark due to a system theme. Yours should be whatever color your other window decorations are.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. What if the option is checked but the bar is still missing?

Comment: @greg - then it's likely something to do with a customization in your desktop environment, something disabling 'window decorations'.

Comment: thanks for your comment. Any idea where this could be? every other app is working fine (I'm using KDE 5)

Comment: (I've tried gnome-control-center and gnome-tweaks)

Comment: I'd guess that that's worth its own question. I don't have an answer, so exposing it to more people may help. It's also a question of its own and not a duplicate (unless someone else has asked). Make an "I tried this solution but it doesn't work" kinda question.

Answer (score 0):

Good news: Google fixed their software and the correct title bar is showing (at least on my system, I hope it's working for you too)